# GPU Image2 Audio Issue

Tags: ios, swift3, gpuimage

I am not getting audio while filtering video using GPUImage2. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
movie = try MovieInput(url:url, playAtActualSpeed:false)

let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first! as String
let uuid1 = CFUUIDCreateString(nil, CFUUIDCreate(nil)) as NSString?

localPath = (documentDirectory as NSString).appendingPathComponent(String(format: "%@.mp4", uuid1!)) as NSString!

print("Filtered Video: %@", localPath)
let fileURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: localPath as String)

do {
    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL)
} catch {
}

movieOutput = try MovieOutput(URL:fileURL, size: Size(width: 720, height: 1280), liveVideo: true)

Filter4 = ColorMatrixFilter()
Filter4.overriddenOutputRotation = Rotation.rotateClockwiseAndFlipVertically

movie --> Filter4 --> renderView

movie.runBenchmark = true
movie.start()

Filter4 --> movieOutput

movieOutput!.startRecording()
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature not implemented in GPUImage2 framework. As you see in `MovieInput` class source code it marked TODO:

```
public init(asset:AVAsset, playAtActualSpeed:Bool = false, loop:Bool = false) throws {
    self.asset = asset
    self.playAtActualSpeed = playAtActualSpeed
    self.loop = loop
    self.yuvConversionShader = crashOnShaderCompileFailure("MovieInput"){try sharedImageProcessingContext.programForVertexShader(defaultVertexShaderForInputs(2), fragmentShader:YUVConversionFullRangeFragmentShader)}

    assetReader = try AVAssetReader(asset:self.asset)

    let outputSettings:[String:AnyObject] = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String):NSNumber(value:Int32(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange))]
    let readerVideoTrackOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track:self.asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], outputSettings:outputSettings)
    readerVideoTrackOutput.alwaysCopiesSampleData = false
    assetReader.add(readerVideoTrackOutput)
    // TODO: Audio here
}
```

You need to check `Camera` class and `audioEncodingTarget` property. Here is code fragment from SimpleVideoRecorder example:

```
movieOutput = try MovieOutput(URL:fileURL, size:Size(width:480, height:640), liveVideo:true)
camera.audioEncodingTarget = movieOutput
```

As you see you should setup audio target and only after that `MovieOutput` class will work. But again `MovieInput` class doesn't support `AudioEncodingTarget`.

Comment: it means its not possible in anyway to filter the saved video with its audio.

Comment: Do you have any idea how we can modify the code to implement it.